# How to Use UniqueDeviceId in ionic/react

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, react-redux, ionic-react, deviceid

i want to get Uniquedeviceid from device and then use it . i fount the solution for angular by in ionic/react i didn't find any suitable solution.
the sample is like this
at first i installed this :

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/unique-device-id@4
```

then when i want to use like this i have an error.

```
constructor(private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID) { }
this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
.then((uuid: any) => console.log(uuid))
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just need the core plugin cordova-plugin-device and you need to call the object device.uuid in order to get the unique device id